# how can i use spring data for apache hadoop for cdh 5.4.x?

Tags: cloudera-cdh, spring-data-hadoop

The official document note that "Spring for Apache Hadoop 2.2 GA" only support CDH 5.3.3

Is there a way to use "spring data hadoop" for CDH 5.4.X or i must wait for the next version ? Will the 2.3 version support CDH 5.4.x ?

Edit:

I've completed this hbase [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/hbase) and this spring boot [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/boot/boot-fsshell)  with Cloudera quick start VM cdh 5.4.2 . So i guess if you just want to do things with Hbase or hadoop shell in CDH 5.4.X, "Spring for Apache Hadoop 2.2 GA" can satify you. If not, please watch the answer of Thomas Risberg below.

The library i used in the Hbase sample is:

```
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.hadoop.version>2.2.0.RELEASE-cdh5</spring.hadoop.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.2</hadoop.version>
        <hbase.version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</hbase.version>
```

The library i used in the spring boot sample is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE-cdh5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next 2.3 version will support CDH 5.4 -- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHDP-494

Since 5.4 uses Hive 1.x we have to remove our Hive/Thrift code and add similar support for Hiveserver2/JDBC. Once that is done we can upgrade to CDH 5.4.

I expect the 2.3 M1 release to be available sometime by mid to late August.